# abrir archivos con bloqueo

Tags: php, xml, indices

Trabajo en un proyecto con php para profesores(mnultiples) y cada vez que un profesor crea una clase, busco en un fichero xml el id de la última clase y crea una nueva. El problema es si dos profesores a la vez quieren crear una clase, como puedo hacer para que el archivo donde están registrados los indices de las clases se bloquee hasta que uno ha creado la clase y no se me creen indices duplicados.

Comment: Una bandera! ... crea una bandera que exista en todos lados, la levantas cuando alguien la este usando y la bajas cuando ya no la usen. Esto se usa a veces en sesiones únicas. Si la bandera esta arriba, pues nadie mas la puede usar. Si esta abajo, alguien la puede usar.

Comment: No es buena idea guardar datos sensibles en archivos porque muchas cosas pueden fallar. Lo adecuado es hacerlo en base de datos. Puedes crear un ciclo para esperar a que se abra el archivo si está bloqueado previamente con [flock()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.flock.php), guardas la información, desbloqueas y cierras el archivo.

Comment: tenia los datos en una base de datos pero cuando trabajas en web y hay muchos profes y muchas clases poniendo registros a saco .. se relentizaba muchisimo. Al poner los datos en archivos xml es ultrarapido, solo que tengo que solucionar un archivo que es común a todos y se toca solo al principio de curso, luego cada profe trabaja con su archivo y es muy rapido.